# Delete an item in a list, if outside the IQR

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to delete an item from a list if it is outside the interquartile range from the median.

Here is the list:

```
l = [69, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 71, 71, 71, 87, 89]
```

The IQR, median and above and below the median are used with `import numpy as np`

```
iqr = np.subtract(*np.percentile(l, [75, 25]))
median = np.percentile(l, 50)
minus = median - iqr
plus = median + iqr
```

The minus number is 69 and the plus is 71 (using the IQR above and below the median)

However, when iterating through the list and trying to delete the items (87, 89) which is above/below the iqr. They are not get removed from the list.

```
for i in l:
    if i < minus:
        del i
    if i > plus:
        del i
```

When I print the list, it still shows 87, 89 in it.

Comment: your loop is not making any changes to the list.. although `i` pops from list, but it's not bounded to list. so `del i` does not touch `l` at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for  ele in l[:]:
    if ele < minus or ele > plus:
        l.remove(ele)
```

You must make a copy of l `l[:]` and mutate the actual list itself using `l.remove`

Comment: I think you mean `l.pop(i)`?

Comment: `IndexError: pop index out of range.` This is with `l.pop(i)`

Comment: @JonathanDavies, use remove but you must make a copy of the list when removing elements, you cannot iterate over and remove elements from the same object

Answer (score 1):

`del` is not the operator you're looking for. It is used to remove a reference to an object and is thus useful in garbage collection.

You're probably looking for this:

```
import numpy as np
l = [69, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 71, 71, 71, 87, 89]
iqr = np.subtract(*np.percentile(l, [75, 25]))
median = np.percentile(l, 50)
minus = median - iqr
plus = median + iqr

arr = np.array(l)
arr[ (minus < arr) & (arr < plus)]
```

Comment: `del` is useful for more than just garbage collection, namely removing an entry from a `dict`. It can be used to delete an entry from a list, too. For example, `x =["a", "b", "c", "d"]`, then `del x[1]` gives `["a", "c", "d"]`.

Comment: @jme, it was only a matter of time before someone would point this out :-)  I'd use the explicit method `pop` of both lists and dicts in both cases as they were designed for this purpose.

Comment: I use each in different scenarios. If I truly want to get rid of the entry, I use `del`. If I want to remove the entry but do something with the value, I use the `pop` method. Seeing a `pop` without assigning the return value makes me uncomfortable, for some reason; `del` seems to me more idiomatic in those cases. Plus `del` provides a concise way to delete slices, like `del x[2:4]`, which, as far as I'm aware, can't be done with a method of a list or dict container.

Comment: @jme, good use case, hadn't considered that!

Answer (score 1):

just convert it to a numpy array and then math from there:

```
l = np.array(l)
l[(l >= 69) & (l <= 71)]
```

that's it.

Comment: I think you've got your boolean logic confused: now you're selecting elements outside of the IQR.

Comment: No problem. Probably only noticed it because we had the same solution in mind.